# How do I import a csv file into R studio?

Tags: r

Download the ’sparrow.csv’ dataset from Blackboard, and read it into R using the ‘read.csv‘ command. You will see columns for species name, sex, wing length, tarsus size, head size, culmen size and weight.

read.csv()

I think I got the data into R but I am not sure

[image]

Comment: From the screenshot it looks as though you are viewing the contents of the CSV file, rather than reading it into R. There is help for every command _e.g._ `?read.csv` - although the help page for that command isn't very good! Remember to assign the result of the command to a variable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way to import data to Rstudio is to use the Import Dataset tab on the Environment tab in the upper right window of RStudio or simply you can use `read.csv` function to do it:

```
df <- read.csv("path/to/Sparrows.csv")
```